# I want to create an NFT, but I don't want to pay the gas fee

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, nft, gas-price, cryptography

I have 10+ creative designs and I want to make NFTs of them, but when I start to make an NFT I see a [gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethereum#Gas) fee that I have to pay to create the NFT, so is there a way to create an NFT for free?

Comment: I believe a write to the blockchain on Ethereum will always require gas. perhaps someone will know something we don't

Comment: first I write there but someone delete my question and told me to ask on etherium

Comment: Try using any popular NFT market places. They now uses meta transactions which offloads gas fee to the purchaser, not the creator. Ref: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/sending-gasless-transactions https://blog.opensea.io/tutorials/sell-your-crypto-collectibles-without-paying-gas/

Comment: "is there any way to create NFT free?" No. Managing the block chain is incredibly computationally (and energetically) expensive, and nobody would want to do it for free. Ultimately, somebody has to pay miners to do this work. The best you can do is forward that cost to buyers.

Answer (score 3):

Most chains have gas fees, so making any state changes will require payment.  Pick a chain with cheaper gas fees if cost is an issue.

Comment: can you suggest any chain?

Comment: Cardano or Near? not really sure sorry.

Answer (score 1):

What about selling on OpenSea which allows lazy minting, so you don't pay gas until the NFT is purchased, as it's also not minted until purchase?

Answer (score 0):

Not free, but cheap - check out tezos and the [HEN market place](https://hicetnunc.art/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of paying zero gas fees is with POAP ([poap.xyz](https://poap.xyz)). Note that they are minted on the xDai chain

Answer (score 0):

Definitely agree with the comments recommending platforms like OpenSea.  They "lazily" mint NFTs, only actually putting them on-chain when they are purchased for the first time.  Additionally, the buyer pays the gas fees, so you do get them for "free" (minus OpenSea's take of the sales).

Alternatively, you could release them on a cheaper EVM compatible chain like [fantom](https://fantom.foundation/) or [avalanche](https://www.avax.network/).  This way you can still use solidity code, but the gas fees will be astronomically lower.  Your users could [bridge](https://nft.anyswap.exchange/#/dashboard) the NFTs to ethereum if they so desire.